# Replace all zero columns with NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, na

I have the following dataframe in R

```
library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

df= data.frame("ID"= c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
"A1"= c(0,0, 0, 0, 1,0,1), "B1"= c(1,0, 1,0, 0, 0, 0))
```

The dataframe appears as follows

```
  ID A1 B1
1  A  0  1
2  A  0  0
3  A  0  1
4  A  0  0
5  B  1  0
6  B  0  0
7  B  1  0
```

I would like to obtain the following dataframe

```
   ID A1 B1
 1  A NA  1
 2  A NA  0
 3  A NA  1
 4  A NA  0
 5  B  1 NA
 6  B  0 NA
 7  B  1 NA
```

I have tried the following code

```
df%>%group_by(ID)%>%
mutate(A1=case_when(sum(A1)==0~NA))%>%
mutate(B1=case_when(sum(B1)==0~NA))
```

This converts A1 and B1 completely to NA values.

I request some help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can use `if/else`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate_all(list(~ if(all(.==0)) NA_integer_ else .))
# ID       A1    B1
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A        NA     1
#2 A        NA     0
#3 A        NA     1
#4 A        NA     0
#5 B         1    NA
#6 B         0    NA
#7 B         1    NA
```

---

Or without any `if/else`

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate_all(~ NA^all(!.) * .)
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, all(x == 0), NA)), ID]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
by(df[-1], df$ID, FUN = function(x)  x * (NA^ !colSums(!!x))[col(x)])
```

Answer (score 3):

We can `group_by` `ID` and use `mutate_all` with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_all(~replace(., all(. == 0), NA))

# ID       A1    B1
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A        NA     1
#2 A        NA     0
#3 A        NA     1
#4 A        NA     0
#5 B         1    NA
#6 B         0    NA
#7 B         1    NA
```

If there are other columns and we want to apply this only to specific columns we can use `mutate_at`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(A1,B1), ~replace(., all(. == 0), NA))
```

---

Using `case_when` we can do this as

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_all(~case_when(all(. == 0) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ .))
```

The problem in OP's attempt was there was no `TRUE` case defined in `case_when` so when no condition is matched it returns `NA` by default. From `?case_when`

> If no cases match, NA is returned.

So if we define the `TRUE` case it would work as expected. Also we should not check for `sum(A1)==0` because if there are negative and positive values in the column (like -2 , +2) they would add up to 0 giving unexpected results.

```
df%>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(A1 = case_when(all(A1 == 0) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ A1), 
         B1 = case_when(all(B1 == 0) ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ B1))
```

Comment: Thank you. can I read it as mutate all columns where each value is 0 with NA.

Comment: @Thilagaraghavan yes, just to be more precise we can also read it as `mutate` for all columns and `replace` values to `NA` if `all` values in the group is 0.

Comment: neat. absolulutely crystal clear. But why does the case when code I wrote not work. I have grouped by ID and then based on colsums ==0, the mutation should take place

Comment: @Thilagaraghavan I added some explanation for `case_when` in the answer.